# cant resolve error: events.some is not a function in severless

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

can not deploy to serverless. I tried digging into the error but it redirected me to completely different file in node module, i.e, alexa-skill.js
[image]

I tried researching about the problem but couldn't find solution to it

here's my serverless.yml:
[image]

I was trying to deploy the db configuration and to setup my config file and lamda function.

Comment: [resolved] the events in my getAirlines function was not properly intended!

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the way events are set up in your serverless.yml file.

The Serverless framework expects events to be defined in a list format, even if you have only one event. Therefore, you need to use the "-" (hyphen) character before each event definition to signal that it's an item in a list (or "array" in YAML terms).

In your case, the issue arises because the "-" (hyphen) is improperly positioned, attached to "http". It looks like this: "-http", but it should be "- http".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).